# For a linear operator $S$ such that $S^2=S$, does the corresponding matrix $A$ in a given basis $B$ preserve the identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Thus, does $A^2 = A$ hold if $S^2 = S$ and $A$ is the matrix corresponding to $S$ in the basis $B$?

Comment: Regardless of the basis, the actual linear transformation represented by the matrix is the same. If you change languages, it shouldn’t change the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Choosing a basis $B$ gives a ring isomorphism between the set of linear transformations $V \rightarrow V$ and the set of $n \times n$ matrices, assuming $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$.  This means that whatever thing you say about a linear transformation $T$ that can be said using $+, \times$, will be also hold for the corresponding matrix $M$, and vice verse.

Comment: So regarding your yes-or-no question, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why we use matrices, when we work with linear operators is due to the fact that there is a linear isomorphism between the set of all linear maps between two distinct spaces and the set of all corresponding matrices.

This means given your linear operator $S:V\to W$ and a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of $V$ and basis $w_1,\dots,w_m$ of $W$, there is a unique matrix $A$ with respect to this basis that satisfies that
$$Sv_k=Av_k \text{ for all }k=1,\dots,n.$$

From here it should be clear that given a basis the identity will always hold for the matrix representation of $S.$